# Samba 4 not shows new files

Tags: linux, ftp, samba, network-share

We have a Debian 8 file server with Samba 4, and there is a network printer-scanner, which send the scanned documents to the server through FTP in PDF format, and in the server the the Scan folder is shared through Samba, and mapped as drive on all client (mostly W7) machine.

And those scanned PDFs **sometimes** do not show up immediately in the share, just after a few minutes, but logging in to the server through SSH, I can see those files that the scanner sent, just the Samba not share them.

And its not just annoying, but if somebody scan a doc, which have to be send immediately in email, she/he is disrupted.

Anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: what version of Windows are the clients running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With W7 as the client OS, look for the issue [as answered here](https://serverfault.com/questions/482174/slow-shared-folder-refresh-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you! Although not checked, but seems it will help. I googled a lot about this issue and not found that question you linked. I thought it is definitely a Samba4 issue and not general SMB. As mentioned there, its sad there is no doc about SMB versions, and also the Samba4's doc is thin.